# Setting Build Type debuggable to True in Android Studio doesn't stick

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

I'm trying to add a second Build Type for my app (so I can test it using Proguard before publishing).  I made changes in the app/build.gradle to reflect what I want:

```
    debugPG {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        applicationIdSuffix '.debugPG'
        versionNameSuffix '.debugPG'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
```

When I try to debug, I get an error saying:

> Error running app:
>
> Cannot debug application from module app on device
>
> This application does not have the debuggable attribute enabled in its manifest.
>
> If you have manually set it in the manifest, then remove it and let the IDE automatically assign it.
>
> If you are using Gradle, make sure that your correct variant is debuggable.

I went to the Android Studio settings for the Build Type (Build / Edit Build Types ...), selected debugPG, and changed Debuggable to True.  (Note - it was grayed out but allowed me to change it).  However when I click OK, it doesn't save the preference and I get the error again.  Opening the setting again shows me it's still stuck on False.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to add debuggable to your custom build type within your gradle file:

```
debugPG {
    ...
    debuggable true
}
```

If that doesn't work, you may want to try turning off proguard.

Comment: Turn off Proguard for my published app?

Comment: No, for this debug variant you are creating.  You do not want to create a release app with debug capabilities turned on.

Comment: Oh the whole point is to test Proguard with debug enabled because I'm finding that my published app stopped working when my debug variant works fine due to a difference in the way PG obscures types. I'm trying the "debuggable true" now... Looks like it's working so far

Comment: I gotcha - I missed that detail.  Proguard definitely plays some games with obfuscation and size reduction.  While it should not fundamentally change the behavior, there are some cases where it can.  So, if you are going to use it you'll need to tread lightly, particularly if you are using any 3rd party libraries.  It's very common to exclude them from proguard's ops.

Answer (score 6):

Change build variant from release --> debug from android studio bottom-left-corner.

[image]